# Fantom testnet keeps disconnecting

Tags: smartcontracts, fantom

Has anyone deployed any smart contracts onto Opera testnet - which endpoint did you use for your deploy?

I'm having a hard time with this one because it fails after either one or several contracts in a series I'm deploying:

`FetchError: request to https://rpc.testnet.fantom.network/ failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`